# Large Forms Design Using MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

i am trying to make a form design in Ms Access 2010, for that firstly entered fields into Access Table. Then try to

```
 Create->Form Wizard
```

Actually my table is too big, so form wizaed is not creating the form . Also i want divide this form into separate parts. I tried "Tabs". But My problem is that when i take the printout of form i want actually get the full form in one print. If i use Tab, that is not possible. How can i solve this problem.

Thank You All

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabs if this is working for you and also create a report that includes all the fields that you need to print out. This report can be activated by a Print button.

Comment: actually i also want to take the printout of the form

Comment: A designed report is usually better than just a screen print of the form. Access lets you customize your report.